# What does inflater.inflate() do?

Tags: android

I went through the API but could not understand well. I could not understand the result of this method. I am completely new to Android & require help.

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Inflating** is the process of adding a view(.xml) to activity on runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a `View` defined in your xml file. E.g. you have a `layout` for a list row.

You want to create a `View` from that xml. E.g. your `ListAdapter` requires you to create a `View` for a list row in `ListAdapter.getView()`;

So by using `inflater.inflate()` you create your `View` from your XML file.

There's also a static method `View.inflate()` which does the same.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, Inflate is a method which parses the first parameter `view` and puts it inside the second parameter `ViewGroup`.
third parameter says, put the view in the `ViewGroup` or not now?
if it's false, You will have to manually `addView(view)` , it's benefits are maybe if you want to add a view based on a condition,

```
If (view != null){
addView(view);
}
```

It's true by default if you didn't specify it.
inflate(R.layout.popup,myLinearLayout,true);
basically, changes the layout file called Popup.xml to a real layout & not just text, then puts in inside the LinearLayout specified in this case , it's myLinearLayout, True says put it now, I have no conditions or anything to do before.

Comment: Best explaintion, covered three parameters

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

### According to documentation

**inflater.inflate will -**

Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws InflateException if there is an error.

In simple terms inflater.inflate is required to create view from XML .It is just like parsing or converting the XML to generate a UI.